# What is the relationship between the uncertainty principle and electron diffraction experiment?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

I know that the uncertainty principle says that we can't measure the position and momentum at the same time but I still can't relate it to the electron diffraction experiment. Isn't that the electron diffraction experiment is used to explain the duality of the nature of electron only?

Comment: see this answer of mine  https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/238855/  . . this link will help https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Quantum_Mechanics/Heisenberg_Uncertainty_Principle

Comment: So can I say that the uncertainty principle provides the lower boundary of the deviation of the electron diffraction experiment from the actual value?

Comment: In general the uncertainty principle provides an envelope for the necessity of using quantum mechanics for the real solutions. The same with the de Broglie wavelength. Masses do not "wave" for individual partilcles, it is the wavefunction derived probability that shows wave properties, as the linked answer shows.But it is useful for estimating the region of necessity of using QM.