# What is the role of the magnetic moment on wave particle duality

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, classical-mechanics, maxwell-equations

An electron, travelling at high speed relative to an observer, does not radiate unless it undergoes some form of acceleration.  Yet we can observe wave like properties under certain measurement conditions. If we accept that the electron has a magnetic moment, then there is a high probability that the electron gained some angular momentum on leaving the source.  This angular momentum of the magnetic moment must exponentially dissipate its energy via radiation. ***Is this wave particle duality?*** Could this explain interference in the double slit experiment with very well spaced electrons?

Comment: There is still  interference in double slit single electron at a time , the wave property is seen with the accumulation of events , single electrons seem random on the screen.  see here https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/238855/is-it-wrong-to-say-that-an-electron-can-be-a-wave/238866#238866

Comment: @anna v...The link looks like the Tonamura et al. experiment. The dots are the vector addition of noise energy plus feeble EM wave energy.  There are two paper referring to this effect:---https://jumpshare.com/v/Zcjz31uwBJJZd0VN7aXF .............................................               /doi.org/10.1023/A:1019771303840

Comment: @anna v....The second reference has a computer simulation of signal plus noise addition. The image in the simulation looks remarkably similar to Tonamura's final image!! The simulation is based on purely classical assumptions.

Comment: @anna v...The electrons arrive randomly and actually reduce contrast of the image by adding a DC component to the image of Tonomuras.