# Why can't waves and particles be used for quantum entanglement communication?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement

I've heard the argument before that you can't know your results match before comparing notes, but I've also heard that the entangled particle is a wave or particle based on whether the other entangled particle is being measured in it's own double slit experiment.

If we can make the entangled particle a wave, how come we can't, with enough particles, make a binary code of wave/particle/wave wave/particle to send messages?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No-communication_theorem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wave/particle duality is a duality that needs an accumulation of measurements with the same boundary conditions to be manifested experimentally.

The particle definition  is extended from the classical mechanics , there is a specific (x,y,z,t) describing the particle. The wave part comes from the quantum mechanical wave function that predicts the **probability** to find the particle at (x,y,z,t) .

This [double slit experiment referred here with electrons one at a time](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/238855/is-it-wrong-to-say-that-an-electron-can-be-a-wave/238866#238866) can give an intuition :

[image]

Each electron leaves a particle-like footprint on the screen, an (x,y) dot, seemingly random. It is the accumulation that gives the wave interference.

> f we can make the entangled particle a wave or not, how come we can't, *with enough particles*, make a binary code of wave/particle/wave wave/particle to send messages?

italics mine

Because you cannot control where the electron will end up on the screen, it is controlled by a probability function. So even in this simple set up, a message cannot be encoded, Messages need  direct control.

Answer (score 1):

My layman understanding is you can entangle particles but you don't get to choose the states they end up in. The entangled states they end up could remain static over time, but could also fluctuate on their own (like noise). Either way, they match.

But the crux is that if you try and touch a particle on one end to force a state to transmit something, that breaks the entanglement. So right there you can't communicate with it.

Furthermore, if you're on the receiving end staring at an entangled particle, you have no idea if the states you are observing are random entangled states or random unentangled states. The only way to check is send records all the way back to the transmission origin, or send records from the transmission origin all the way to the destination to check. That means you also can't use the particle becoming unentangled as a form of communication. (For example, preparing a million entangled particle pairs in advance and shipping them to the receiving end and using them up there as you disentangle them to communicate).