# Dual nature of matter on macroscopic bodies like that of humans or anything

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wave-particle-duality

if matter has a dual nature and everything is made up of matter then why do macroscopic bodies like humans or trees or a cars is not showing wave motion like why are they static and not moving like a wave?

Comment: Brownian motion is not wave-like, so it’s unclear what you’re asking. Also, what do you mean by “dual nature”?

Comment: very sorry for my mistake i am still in high school.

Comment: i wanted to ask that if matter has wave nature then why we are not moving like waves

Comment: i was referring to particle and wave nature when i stated dual nature

Comment: Clarifications to questions should be made by editing the question. Comments are not considered clarifications.

Comment: i edited my question thank you for correcting me i am new here

Comment: maybe my answer here will help seeing the difference . It is about electrons, but the dimensional argument with h holds for macroscopic bodies. https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/238855/is-it-wrong-to-say-that-an-electron-can-be-a-wave/238866#238866

Comment: @annav i read your answer and most it went upways my head as i said i am still in highschool can you explain it to me in simpler terms i want to know that after neils bohr atomic model de broglies theory said that electrons show wave nature i want to ask that do electrons move in the oribits performing circular motion or they move like waves also when they perform movements in the atom do they make any patterns or their every moment is random

Comment: i read so many answers and questions on this website and now i am much more confused than before please forgive me if i asked something BS

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: in an atom do electron revolve around the nucleus doing circular motion or does it moves like a wave

Comment: please provide an image for visualisation when i googled it i mostly found the circulation motion of electron images

Comment: @AnugrahSengar In a few words,  matter at the microscopic level of atoms cannot be describe by normal waves of stuff moving about or around. Quantum mechanics was invented in order to have a mathematical way of predicting the data and observations at the microscopic level. An individual particle, atom molecule does not "wave". The wave nature appears over an accumulation of observations and this accumulation is modeled by QM as a probability distribution that can be predicted by the QM theory. This holds for microscopic dimensions. Once dimensions become large the QM effects become incoherent.